# multer gives me error "originalname" of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, multer

I'm trying to make an image uploader but I'm getting this error whenever I try to upload an image. i think all the configurations I've made with multer are alright so I can't seem to find where is the error.

I'm doing this with the multer module. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it as I've been trying to solve this error for quite a while and I keep getting the same error.

server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer  = require('multer');

const Clients = require('../models/clients.js')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, "./uploads")
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({storage: storage})

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    Clients.find()
    .then(client => res.json(client))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})

router.route('/add', upload.single("articleimage")).post((req, res) => {
  
    const newClient = new Clients({
      image: req.file.originalname,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      weight: req.body.weight,
      BMI: req.body.BMI
    })
  
    newClient.save()
    .then (() => res.json(newClient))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err))
})

module.exports = router
```

Client side:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import FileBase64 from 'react-file-base64';
import axios from 'axios'

function AddClient() {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState('')
    const [BMI, setBMI] = useState('')
    const [image, setImage] = useState('')

    const selectedFile = (e) => {
        setImage(e.target.files[0])
    }
    console.log(image)

    const submitForm = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData()

        formData.append("image", image)
        formData.append("firstName", firstName)
        formData.append("lastName", lastName)
        formData.append("weight", weight)
        formData.append("BMI", BMI)

          axios.post('http://localhost:4000/clients/add', formData)
          .then(res => console.log(res))
    }

    console.log(firstName)

    return (
        <div>
<form class="w-full max-w-lg" onSubmit={submitForm} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
  <input type="file" filename="articleimage" onChange={selectedFile}/>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        First Name
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" type="text" onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} placeholder="First Name" />
      <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">Please fill out this field.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Last Name
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Last Name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        Weight
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" type="text" onChange={(e) => setWeight(e.target.value)} placeholder="Weight" />
      <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">Please fill out this field.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Body Mass Index (BMI)
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" onChange={(e) => setBMI(e.target.value)} placeholder="BMI" />
    </div>
    <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Add Client</button>
  </div>
</form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default AddClient
```

Comment: Can you try to console.log(req.file) before const newClient = new Clients({? And add that console.log() in the question.

Comment: how can you console.log in server side? When I put the console.log, nothing is outputted

Comment: Just do console.log('File: ', req.file);

Comment: it says ```File: undefined```

Comment: That means that Multer did not upload file, and that is why you can not access the originalname property.. Do you see you file uploaded?

Comment: and why can that be due to?

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side, you are appending the formData as `formData.append("image", image)` but on the server-side, you are writing **'articleimage'** in the `upload middleware`.
Change it to **'image'** i.e. same as the client-side.

Also, I would suggest that the **controller code for uploading/saving the image and saving the name of the image in the database should be separated.**

You should create a new controller function that just saves the image on your server and returns the name of the image. Call this controller function through an API call in the  `selectedFile` callback function. And then, save the returned name of the image in the state and finally proceed to submit the form and save the data in the database.

Comment: still not working after changing the name on the server-side and the client-side

Comment: Is it still giving the same error? ```undefined```?

Comment: Has it been solved? Because I copied your whole code-base and tested it out. It was giving me the same error until I changed the server code a little bit. I refactored the route function from this:- ```router.route('/add', upload.single("articleimage")).post((req, res) => {}``` to this:- ```router.route('/add').post(upload.single("image"), (req,res)=>{}```. Try this out if you are still getting the error.